# What is error sql72009?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I got a lot of errors as below with my **database project, Visual Studio 2013**. However I don't use any of below dlls anymore (I used them before, but I removed them from references).

```
Error SQL72009: [Accessibility] has an unresolved dependency to 
[System.Windows.Forms]. A deployment script with correct ordering cannot be 
created.

Error SQL72009: [System.Design] has an unresolved dependency to [System.Web]. 
A deployment script with correct ordering cannot be created.

Error SQL72009: [System.Windows.Forms] has an unresolved dependency to 
[System.Web]. A deployment script with correct ordering cannot be created.

Error SQL72009: [System.Windows.Forms] has an unresolved dependency to 
[System.Design]. A deployment script with correct ordering cannot be created.

Error SQL72009: [System.Windows.Forms] has an unresolved dependency to 
[System.Drawing.Design]. A deployment script with correct ordering cannot be 
created.

Error SQL72009: [System.Windows.Forms] has an unresolved dependency to 
[Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0]. A deployment script with correct ordering cannot 
be created.
....
```

**So my question is:**

1. What exactly does error sql72009 mean?
2. When does it happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unresolved reference to object \[INFORMATION\_SCHEMA\].\[TABLES\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096029/unresolved-reference-to-object-information-schema-tables)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem using SQL Server Data Tools, and in my case, the problem was a circular dependency: two functions referenced each other.