# Fix "Unresolved Reference" errors using sys.columns in a different database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSDT Solution with two database projects, let's call them `MainDb` and `OtherDb`. I'm trying to create a view on the `MainDb` database which surfaces some information about related objects in the `OtherDB` database. For simplicity, here's an example of the type of query I want in the view:

```
create view dbo.RelatedTables
as
select m.Name
from sys.tables m
where exists
(
    select 1
    from OtherDb.sys.tables o
    where m.name = o.name
)
```

The problem is, I'm getting an error in my `MainDb` project saying:

> Error     SQL71561: View: [dbo].[RelatedTables] has an unresolved reference to object [OtherDb].[sys].[columns].

I have:

- A database reference to the `OtherDb` project in my `MainDb` project
- A reference to the `master` database in my `MainDb` project

  - I know you need a reference to the `master` database in order [to remove "unresolved reference" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096029/unresolved-reference-to-object-information-schema-tables)
- A database reference to the `master` database in my `OtherDb` project

  - I'm able to write views in *that* project that reference the local `sys.columns` just fine.

Is anyone aware of how to configure an SSDT project to build when a view on one database has to reference a catalog view on a different database?

Comment: Configure a SQLCMD variable in the referencing MainDb project named "OtherDb" with a default value "OtherDb" and change the database name in the 3-part reference to the variable using SQLCMD variable syntax. E.g. [$(OtherDb)].sys.tables

Comment: One such variable was actually created when I set up the reference from "MainDb" to "OtherDb", but if I replace `OtherDb.sys.columns` with `[$(OtherDb)].sys.columns` it just says "unresolved reference to object [$(OtherDb)].[sys].[columns]". If I remove the square brackets around `[$(OtherDb)]` I get the error "Incorrect syntax near $(OtherDb)" (making me think it's not respecting the SQLCMD variable somehow)

Comment: The enclosures around the SQLCMD variable name are required. It's been a while since I used projects with cross-database references so I created a couple of database projects and was able to duplicate the error you see. However, the project still built successfully and published too. Is that also true for you? Also, I set the `Suppress References Warnings` property of the database reference to `true` and it made no difference.

Comment: That's a good question; I'm actually in this project right now because it not building, but that's for a number of issues, not just this one. So let me resolve the other issues, then see if it builds. If it does, we can close this out.

Comment: This smells of an SSDT bug so I updated VS to the latest version (SSDT 17.8.119.0) but I still see the message as an error, even though it's treated as a (false) warning. Maybe someone else can chime in if there's something we've overlooked.

Comment: After clearing up some of the other build problems, I was indeed able to build the project. So super weird, but I guess it's fixed (or at least a non issue?) Thanks @DanGuzman